# SQL Server - Create subset table having 2 largest values in row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table (11 columns) having only one row. It contains below records:

```
ID   Data_Type  Value1      Value2      Value3      Value4      Value5      Value6      Value7      Value8      Value9      
1    A_1        08/03/2020  08/03/2020  08/03/2020  08/02/2021  08/02/2021  08/02/2021  08/09/2022  08/09/2021  08/09/2024
```

I need a subset table with below records (Only 2 columns having latest date values)

```
ID  Data_Type   Value9      Value7
1   A_1         08/09/2024  08/09/2022
```

Please help.

Comment: This would be a lot easier with a properly normalized data model

Comment: Its SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, I'd first change your data structure and merge all value columns into one as values are a lot easier to compare with each other when they're in the same column (like trying to sort and filter values in an Excel spreadsheet - You would usually transpose the columns into one then sort/filter it).

One way that you can merge all value columns into one column is by using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT ID, Data_Type, Value1 AS NewValue INTO NewTable FROM Table UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Data_Type, Value2 FROM Table UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Data_Type, Value3 FROM Table UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Data_Type, Value4 FROM Table UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Data_Type, Value5 FROM Table UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Data_Type, Value6 FROM Table UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Data_Type, Value7 FROM Table UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Data_Type, Value8 FROM Table UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Data_Type, Value9 FROM Table
```

After you've done this and all the new data is in NewTable, you can use the following query to extract the top 2 values:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * 
FROM NewTable 
ORDER BY NewValue DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot the data using `APPLY` and then use some aggregation logic:

```
select t.id, t.data_type, v.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then date end) as date_1,
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as date_1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then date end) as date_2,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as date_2             
      from (select v.*, row_number() over (order by value desc) as seqnum
            from (values (t.value1, 'value1'),
                         (t.value2, 'value2'),
                         (t.value3, 'value3'),
                         . . .
                 ) v(date, value)
           ) v
     ) v;
```

Very important note:  This adds *four* columns, not *two* columns.  The name of the column with the maximum and penultimate value is in a separate column.  You can only control the names of the columns if you use dynamic SQL.

The above will work fine on one row.  But it will also work on multiple rows as well.